# localize an ios app programmatically swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I'm developing an app with 2 languages English and Arabic, it works fine on 9.2 devices, but when testing it on 8.3 device layout doesn't flip from right to left or vice verse, but it loads the selected language text normally, also

```
  print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(" AppleLanguages"));
```

returns nil.

I'm using this code to change language

```
   if lang == "en"{
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(["ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        LanguageManager.saveLanguageByIndex(3)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("langChanged", object: nil)

    }else{
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(["en"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        LanguageManager.saveLanguageByIndex(0)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("langChanged", object: nil)
    }
```

and in appDelegete

```
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
```

so what am I missing?!

I'm using xcode 7.2, and the issue happens on 8.3 devices only

here're some pictures of what happens and what should have happened!

Thanks,

[image]

[image]

Comment: right-to-left language support was added in iOS 9, see http://9to5mac.com/2015/06/08/right-to-left-languages-ios9/ It can still work in iOS 8, but you will have to set the layout programmatically to right-to-left to my knowledge

Comment: Thanks, Hmmm I forgot to say when I close and open app most of the layout flip correctly, but I've to close and open it manually, and using Exit(0) is not acceptable by apple, and also it closes only the app and I want to reopen it automatically, also I already used restart code above, but it seems it doesn't work in 8.3!!!

Comment: Seem like Apple made the interface change dynamically in iOS 9. You will have to make the text alignment changes in iOS 8 yourself.